# Creating an app with MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I had got an excel document that have calendar in it. It shows the calendar for year between 1990-2078. Just have to enter the year and press the enter key then, it will display the whole calendar for the year got entered. I want to learn how to do this. Has anybody got this?

You can find the excel document in the link, get it downloaded and see it your self. Any one familiar with it, help me out a little to go through it. How to develop such apps and also deploy it. Thanks in advance to you!

[link for the calendar app document with excel](https://www.box.com/s/8fcf4ef9f99a824e4bdc)

Comment: you should specify specify for which OS / programming language you would like to get this done..

Comment: No language yaar it excel and may be done for any os i think so.....

Comment: Did you create that excel document or are you trying to create something like it? If you're trying to create something like it, just look at the formulas in each of the cells to see what is happening.

Comment: @NickSlash i want to make similar excel document

Answer (score 0):

As there are  no lang. specified, here's an example in C:
http://www.codingunit.com/how-to-make-a-calendar-in-c